# How to read data from figures with mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, figure

I have drawn a figure with Mathematica, and want to read data from the figure. For example, there exists a Square Wave with the following code, and I want the value of the third turning point:

```
R[t_] := 10 UnitStep[-Sin[0.4 Pi t]];
Plot[R[t], {t, 0, 20}, Exclusions -> None, PlotStyle -> Thick]
yui = Flatten[Table[{t, (R[t] /. sol)}, {t, 5, 10, 1.2}]]
Partition[yui, 2] // TableForm
```

I make efford to read the value of the function wave. Due to the continuity of the curve, the value I read in this way may not be the right one.

Then, I use the command "Solve" with the following code:

```
Solve[R[t] = 5, {t, 5, 10, 1.2}]
```

But it does not work!

**I really want to obtain the coordination, but with the wanted y value to get the exact x value.**

Hence I need your help!

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19859/plot-extract-data-to-a-file

Comment: Thanks for your help! I try the method you offer in the example. However, the range (The precision or the step of extract data) is an important problem. To be more exactly, I need to extract the value of when the square wave trigger (up or down), so in this case the method may not be a good one. Specifically, I want to read the data when two curve intersect: the line of y=5 and the square wave with the peak value of 10.

Comment: `UnitStep` changes discontinuously from 0 to 1, so `R` is never 5. Isnt your solution just `5 n/ 2` anyway?